# how to run two sequential merges in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am running a SQL request such as

```
SELECT data1.agent_name, data2.agent_phone 
FROM mydata data1 
INNER JOIN mydata2 data2 ON data1.ID = data2.ID
```

The problem is that I would like to further merge the resulting dataset (above) with another table, **data3** using a `LEFT JOIN` on `data1.ID2` from data1 and `data3.ID2` from data3.

**Is this possible in the same request**?

Thanks!

Comment: yes..it is possible.You can join how many ever tables you want

Comment: great thank you, could you show me how the syntax would be?

Comment: Simply add LEFT JOIN etc at the end.

Comment: `SELECT data1.agent_name, data2.agent_phone 
FROM mydata data1 
INNER JOIN mydata2 data2 ON data1.ID = data2.ID left join data3 on data3.id2=data1.id2`